# How do I turn PUG into JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pug

I am trying to use some code written in Pug, in a JS react app.

I have found this plugin [here](https://github.com/pugjs/babel-plugin-transform-react-pug) that will convert the code, but there is a problem. It states that it cannot convert "." statements, of which there are a few.

So what do I replace the "."s with to make it work (or alternatively if anyone could convert it to react JS that would be fantastic!

The Pug code I wish to use:

```pug
- const droplets = 250
.rain
  - for (let r = 0; r < droplets; r++)
    svg.rain__drop(preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin", viewBox='0 0 5 50', style=`--x: ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}; --y: ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}; --o: ${Math.random()}; --a: ${Math.random() + 0.5}; --d: ${(Math.random() * 2) - 1}; --s: ${Math.random()}`)
      path(stroke='none', d="M 2.5,0 C 2.6949458,3.5392017 3.344765,20.524571 4.4494577,30.9559 5.7551357,42.666753 4.5915685,50 2.5,50 0.40843152,50 -0.75513565,42.666753 0.55054234,30.9559 1.655235,20.524571 2.3050542,3.5392017 2.5,0 Z")
```

Comment: You cannot "convert" to React, since React is not a well defined language, it's a paradigm - there are multiple ways to do similar things. Pug, JSX on the other hand are languages. Of course, you can select a fixed way to do things, but the conversion won't be always be good React code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.rain__drop
```

is parsed into this HTML markup

```
class="rain__drop"
```

which would mean this JSX:

```
className="rain__drop"
```

---

As a rule of thumb, if you have the possibility to run the app, you can always inspect the resulting markup.

Probably useful: [Pug: interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html).
Probably even more useful: [PUG to HTML](https://pughtml.com/). Tip: combine it with [HTML to JSX](https://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm).
Copy/paste time!